# Cast model or instantiate a new object based on the model assigned to the view at passing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two similar problems that I think might have the same answer. In our project we have two cases where we can't use the model that is being passed from the controller. Due to limitations in the framework we are using we can't really change models being passed in a way that makes any sense to the rest of the application so that is unfortunately a no go.

---

First problem is that I got a lot of logic in the view that clutters the view:

```
@model ISomeModel
@{
    // A lot of code here
    var variableToUse = somethingFromeAbove;
}

<div>
    @variableToUse.SomeProperty
</div>
```

Here it would make sense to do something like this instead:

```
@model ISomeModel
@{
    var anotherModel = new SomeMethod(Model);
}

<div>
    @anotherModel.SomeProperty
</div>
```

However, in this case the first model is not used at all, so we more or less ends up with a redundant model. Here this bodge would be a possible solution (if it was a feature in the RazorEngine, that is):

```
@model new SomeMethod(ISomeModel)

<div>
    @Model.SomeProperty
</div>
```

---

The other problem is that I can only get an IBaseModel from another action (long story involving an enterprise CM and reflection...), but I know what it is that is coming in and want to access properties etc, some here though that I end up with a redundant model:

```
@model IBaseModel
@{
    var CastedModel = (IMySpecificModel)Model;
}

<div>
    @CastedModel.SomePropertyNotAvalibleOnIBaseModel
</div>
```

Here this one would have been a little bit cleaner:

```
@model (IEnumerable<ISomeInterfaceDerivingFromIBaseModel>)IEnumerable<IBaseModel>

<div>
    @Model.SomePropertyNotAvalibleOnIBaseModel
</div>
```

---

I guess I could just go with the (working, not fake) solutions I have but it must be a cleaner way, right? However the cases are so specific (it only occurs once or twice in the entire project) that it feels wrong to put the logic in some helper class or method extension since those are typically more general and useful in more than just one edge case. Any ideas?

Comment: _"However, in this case the first model is not used at all"_. It isn't completely true, you used it to build anotherModel. You may also try to use dynamic instead of a typed model (I don't like that much, I admit) and simply overwrite the old one with the new one

Comment: Sounds like this should be wrapped in *your* controller.  You say you can only get specific type from "another controller" - don't use that controller, use *your own* controller than you have control over.  Seems strange to be writing views for 3rd party *controllers*.

Comment: It's my very own controllers (changed "another controller" to "another action", not that it makes any difference but just to clarify). The issue is that we are using reflection and gets an _object_ in return. Maybe I just need to write a question on proper casting using reflection (since the type is only stored as a variable, I use IBaseModel to do a cast to something more useful and that's what get's passed to the views) but that dosen't solve the first problem.